# Monochrome CRT, words are wavy and sometimes move forward and backward, what could be the issue?

Tags: crt-monitor, power

Monochrome CRT characters are not stable and rather shaking or waviness in them, sometime feel like moving forward and backward. Issue is in the high voltage power supply but what could it be, do high anode ripple can play part in this?

Comment: Are you sure that it's the CRT and not the video output?

Comment: What type of computer/video card? What model CRT?

Comment: Is there anything nearby that might be generating a strong, shifting magnetic field?

Comment: Anode voltage ripple would cause varying picture size, *both* horizontally and vertically. If you just observe horizontal ripple, check the "horizontal position" potentiometer and the hsync pin for bad contact.

Comment: How old is the CRT? Electronic parts tend to degrade over time, especially capacitors.

Comment: How much movement? What is the mains frequency, and what is producing the video signal?

Comment: 1. I mean yes its something else that is generating the issue most likely my hvps.

Comment: 2. CRT is some old model, projection CRT.

Comment: Most like my hvps is causing the issue, anode output is 20kV with ripple voltage of 400pk-pk, also the ripples are of multiple frequency, most likely a clutter or harmonics

Comment: I can observe the movement with my naked  eye.

Comment: Are you using a 60Hz CRT system in an area with a 50Hz mains? Yes, these things SHOULD not interfere but actually they sometimes did, and monitor design relied on the image being slightly distorted but stable by being synchronous with the mains....